# 401 when calling WLAuthorizationManager.login("scope")

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented the new MFP 8 Beta security concept. The positive case, with valid credentials is working fine and the processSuccess method that I have defined is executed.

Unfortunately, the negative case doesn’t work.

After calling the WLAuthorizationManager.login("scope"), I am getting a 401 in the console:

```
2016-05-20 13:48:41.965 Inspector[98311:1660747] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper.m:376 :: Starting the request with URL http://172.20.10.4:9080/mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize
2016-05-20 13:48:41.983 Inspector[98311:1655477] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper requestFailed:responseObject:error:] in WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper.m:419 :: Request Failed
2016-05-20 13:48:41.984 Inspector[98311:1655477] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper requestFailed:responseObject:error:] in WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper.m:422 :: Response Status Code : 401
2016-05-20 13:48:41.984 Inspector[98311:1655477] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper requestFailed:responseObject:error:] in WLAFHTTPSessionManagerWrapper.m:424 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401)
```

Here is my implementation:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login("UserLogin",{
                'username':$scope.username, 
                'password':$scope.password
            }).then( function () {
                console.log(">> WLAuthorizationManager.login - onSuccess");
               $scope.getInspectorDetails().then(
                    function(){
                        $scope.loginInProgress = false;
                        $state.go("inspectionList");
                    }
                );                   
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(">> WLAuthorizationManager.login - onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
               $scope.loginInProgress = false;
                if (!$scope.loginError){
                    $scope.loginError = "Could not connect to server. Please try again later.";
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
```

And the Challenge handler:

```
$scope.registerChallengeHandler = function(){        
    console.log(">> in $scope.registerChllangeHandler ... ");
    $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createWLChallengeHandler($scope.securityCheckName);    
    $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName = $scope.securityCheckName;    

    $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(challenge) {
        console.log(">> in UserLoginChallengeHandler - userLoginChallengeHandler.handleChallenge ...");
// When a session has expired, this will be our entry point into automatically logging back in
    // (since the next server call the user tries to make will end up being flagged as a 'custom response'
    // which will trigger the challenge hander.  Thus, we need to turn on the progress spinner...
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.loginInProgress = true;
    });


        //show the login ...                     
        $scope.user = { username: "", password: ""};            
        $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
        console.log(">> $location.path(): " + $location.path());

        if (!$state.is("login")){
                $state.go("login");
            }         
        $scope.isChallenged = true;
        var statusMsg = "Remaining Attempts: " + challenge.remainingAttempts;
        if (challenge.errorMsg !== null){
            statusMsg = statusMsg + "<br/>" + challenge.errorMsg;                
            $timeout(function(){   
                //want to show only when submit user/pass not when token expired ...
                if($scope.currentPath == "/"){
                    $scope.loginError = statusMsg;    
                }                    
             }, 300);        
        }
        console.log(">>> statusMsg : " + statusMsg);
    };

    $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler.processSuccess = function(data) {                
        console.log(">> in UserLoginChallengeHandler - userLoginChallengeHandler.processSuccess ...");        
        $scope.isChallenged = false;     
        $timeout(function(){        
                $scope.user = { username: "", password: ""};
        }, 200);                    
        $state.transitionTo("inspectionList");                
    };

    $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleFailure = function(error) {
        console.log(">> in UserLoginChallengeHandler - userLoginChallengeHandler.handleFailure ...");
        console.log(">> handleFailure: " + error.failure);
        $scope.isChallenged = false;
        if (error.failure !== null){
            alert(error.failure);
        } else {
            alert("Failed to login.");
        }
    };
}
```

I would have expected that the handleFailure Method is called, but in the debugger I saw that it is not being executed. After the call of WLAuthorizationManager it just stops, so even the WLAuthorizationManager.login – onFailure is not called.

Edit:
Captured the traffic with Wireshark: https://ibm.box.com/s/7mtwsgea06i4bpdbdz0wvyhy3wpma58r

Comment: Are you using the UserLogin security check provided in the sample application or one of your own? Can you add it or link to it?

Comment: Can you Wireshark it to see what is sent to the server when you try to login?

Comment: @IdanAdar: yes, this is the one provided as sample by MFP.

Comment: @NathanH edited the question with the capture results. Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: When you enter wrong credentials, the framework calls `handleChallenge` again, NOT `handleFailure`. Wrong credentials is not considered a failure.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand what is going on. I am still a bit wondering, if WLAuthorizationManager.login() behaves correctly. As it is used with a .then(function {onSuccess}, function {onFailure)) promise. Can you confirm that it is not designed to work with the .then promise and the only way to check for login failure is to check for challenge.errorMsg in the challenge handler?

Comment: I've clarified this in a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `WLAuthorizationManager.login()` with wrong credentials, the normal flow is that the challenge handler's `handleChallenge` will be called, to allow the user to try again.

In some cases, the security check might send a failure, such as "maximum attempt reached". In this case, the challenge handler's `handleFailure` is called.

`WLAuthorizationManager.login()` has its own failure scenarios. For example, let's say your server is down, there is no network, the security check does not exist, etc. In those cases, since there is no challenge involved, the `login`'s failure will be called. That's when your `then` promise will come in handy.